# How can I make Business Object Layer Automatically in Eclipse using database Tables like in Visual Studio

Tags: android, eclipse, visual-studio-2012, sqlite

I am developing an android app in which local Db is used. I want to create some model classes for objects that will be used in whole program. I had already used Visual Studio 2013 and there was a support for such thing in it. I want to know that which will be the fastest way to create BOL (Business Object Layer) in eclipse.

Comment: VS creates classes from database tables automatically?
Also, Eclipse isn't the supported Android IDE anymore for quite a while. Use Android Studio.

Comment: Yeah VS does in entity frame work 5.0, 6.0 which is tested by myself. Any ways thanks for your suggestion